# Update Value on Vuetify Slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What I'm trying todo is update the value when the slider position has moved.

[codepen]https://codepen.io/JakeHenshall/pen/WLezNg

```
<div id="app">
   <v-app id="inspire">
<v-card flat color="transparent">

  <v-subheader>Tick labels</v-subheader>

  <div v-if="value == 0">
     {{ ticksLabels[0] }}
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="value === 1">
    {{ ticksLabels[1] }}
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="value === 2">
    {{ ticksLabels[2] }}
  </div>
        <div v-else-if="value === 3">
    {{ ticksLabels[3] }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    {{ ticksLabels[4] }}
  </div>

  <v-card-text>
    <v-slider
      v-model="fruits"
      :tick-labels="ticksLabels"
      :max="4"
      step="1"
      ticks="always"
      tick-size="2"
    ></v-slider>
  </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

Javascript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        value: 0,
        ticksLabels: [
          '0 - £5k',
          '£5k - £10k',
          '£10k - £25k',
          '£25k - £50k',
          '£50k+'
        ]
      }
    }
  })
```

Any help with this would be great and some info on how to tidy up the if statement would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you got to do,

1. The `fruits` that you are using as `v-model` on your `v-slider` has no reference whatsoever, meaning its not declared anywhere. So ensure to use a model that is declared, `value` has been declared but never used, so you could use that has your model.
2. Use the model both on the slider and the text value which represents the
   position of the slider that way you can eliminate all the `ifs`.

Such as this

```
<v-text-field v-model="ticksLabels[value]"
              class="mt-0"
              type="text"></v-text-field>

<v-card-text>
  <v-slider v-model="value"
            :tick-labels="ticksLabels"
            :max="4"
            step="1"
            ticks="always"
            tick-size="2"></v-slider>
```

Here is your updated codepen https://codepen.io/jayas/pen/QzLrZd

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your if clause at all. To get the index of your selected item, use `v-model="value"` (as you already do, just 'fruits' is probably wrong) and replace your if clause with this tiny piece of code:

```
<div>
  {{ticksLabels[value]}}
</div>
```

I've updated your fiddle [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLWYoM)